# How was Thangorodrim "broken" in "The Fellowship of the Ring"?

Tags: meaning, j-r-r-tolkien, the-lord-of-the-rings

From *The Fellowship of the Ring*, book II, chapter II, page 273:

> 'And not so many, nor so fair, as when Thangorodrim was **broken**, and the Elves deemed that evil was ended for ever, and it was not so.'

What does "broken" mean here?

Answer (score 3):

This refers to the War of Wrath during the First Age. Thangorodrim referrred to three volcanic peaks raised by Morgoth (see chapter 9, "Of the flight of the Noldor" in *The Silmarillon*) Chapter 24, "Of the voyage of Eärendil and the War of Wrath", explains (emphasis added),

> But Eärendil came, shining with white flame, and about Vingilot were
> gathered all the great birds of heaven and Thorondor was their captain, and there
> was battle in the air all the day and through a dark night of doubt. Before the
> rising of the sun Eärendil slew Ancalagon the Black, the mightiest of the dragon-
> host, and cast him from the sky; and **he fell upon the towers of Thangorodrim,
> and they were broken in his ruin**.

In other words, when the great dragon Ancalagon was killed, its fall crushed the towers of Thangorodrim.

Answer (score 0):

Thangorodrim was destroyed in the war that brought down Morgoth -- the dragon  Ancalagon fell on them and crushed them.